# React-select: weird look inside of react-table filter cell, is it problem with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm using React-table to represent my data and I wanted to filter every column using react-select with multiselect option. The problem is that select that I use look very weird when it is in filter table cell:

[image]

What I want to do/have:

- search field is needed (sometimes there is a lot of options to select)
- input with selected options should be fit to column width but heigh can change so if user select many items if they don't fit they should be moved to the next line

[image]

I've prepared fiddle - in the first column is the same situation as in my project. Maybe someone can help me with this issue? Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-custom-filtering-multiple-values-filter-tjtl3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged the actual website of react-select

Link: https://react-select.com/home

This behavior is normal for the input box sizing, only issue is you are getting border for the input.

To Quickly solve that i will recommend you use css selector and target the search input for border

```
.ReactTable .Select-input input {
    border: none;
}
```

Tried in your code and working as expected

[image: solution]